# WP-CLI - Selecting PHP version

Tags: php, errors, wp-cli

On a development server I have a co-install of **PHP 5.6 & 7**; nginx is configured with **PHP 5.6**. When I type "wp" it returns several errors and at the end of the error is a message containing the following:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Typing wp --info returns:

> PHP binary:    /usr/bin/php7.0
>   PHP version:    7.0.10-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1
>   php.ini used:   /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
>   WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
>   WP-CLI packages dir:
>   WP-CLI global config:   /srv/www/wp-cli.yml
>   WP-CLI project config:
>   WP-CLI version: 0.26.0-alpha-5672b63

WP-CLI seems to be defaulting to PHP 7, I would prefer it to use PHP 5.6.

So I was wondering if there was an option I could add to the configuration yml file to select which PHP version to use?

If you need any further information, please let me know

Comment: By the time WP CLI loads the yml file, it's already running inside PHP, the answer to this will depend on your environment, OS, and how PHP is installed, take a look at stuff like PHPBrew etc

Comment: As an aside, you should have mysqli installed, such an extension is available for PHP7 too, although the mysql extension is unsupported and should be avoided. Also, always work from the first error/warning down, the 2nd error may only occur when the 1st one occurs

Answer (score 16):

On a system where

- you can't change the `/usr/bin/php` symlink
- you can't change the `PATH` to point to a different version (because the php executables don't reside in distinct `/lib/` directories)
- `WP_CLI_PHP` has no effect

(like my Arch Linux with `php`(8), `php7` installed from *extra* and `wp-cli` installed from AUR. I'm using php7 vs php8 here, but this should work for any versions.)

…a workaround may be to call the `wp` phar executable with `php7` cli:

```
whereis wp
# /usr/bin/wp

php7 /usr/bin/wp cli info
# PHP binary:     /usr/bin/php7
# PHP version:    7.4.25
```

for convenience you can add a bash alias in your `.bashrc`:

```bash
alias wp-php7='php7 /usr/bin/wp'
# or override wp altogether
alias wp='php7 /usr/bin/wp'
```

Comment: a brilliant solution

Comment: this is actually best solution in my usecase.. I've had virtual users (no home root could be writen any file)  - Thanks @kubi

Answer (score 13):

Got the same problem! Just switch the php version.
On my server PHP5.6 was default for apache, while CLI was configured with PHP7.1. After installing WP-CLI, with `wp --info` I got this result:

```
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php7.1
PHP version: 7.1.5-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1
php.ini used: /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir: phar://wp-cli.phar
```

And when i used the wp core install command i got the error: Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
The problem is just the mix between the different versions: we have just to switch completely to 5.6 or 7.1.
In my case problem was solved simply by writing on the shell:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

And then `wp --info`

```
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php5.6
PHP version: 5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2
php.ini used: /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir: phar://wp-cli.phar
```

Problem solved! WP-CLI worked like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

You can set the php binary that WP-CLI uses by setting an environment variable in your linux shell.

```
export WP_CLI_PHP=/path/to/php5.6
```

Comment: According to the documentation this only works if you've installed wp-cli via git or composer. I wasn't able to get it to work with wp-cli installed via yum on CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to change your default PHP version.

I assume `php -v` returns 7?

You'll need to change the PATH.

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206864/use-different-php-version-cli-executable-for-one-command

Or this: https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/#using-a-custom-php-binary